# Jni crash when calling it from java backgroundThread, from main thread it works

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-native-interface

Hi im trying to grab the camerapreview frames and to convert them in a java background thread wich calls jni methods from it.
Running that code in the uithread works.
source is [here](https://github.com/troop/FreeDcam/tree/master/imageconverter)

I'm storing the native ref in a ByteBuffer which gets init when calling the INIT() method from jni

Java:

```
private ByteBuffer nativeHandler = null;
private synchronized static native ByteBuffer INIT();
```

jni:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_troop_com_imageconverter_ImageProcessorWrapper_INIT(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    ImageProcessor* rgbContainer = new ImageProcessor();
    jobject g = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(rgbContainer, 0);
    return g;
}
```

when let running it on the ui thread it works

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        ImageProcessorWrapper imageProcessor = new ImageProcessorWrapper();
        imageProcessor.ProcessFrame(data.clone(), w, h);
        imageProcessor.ApplyHPF();

    }
```

putting this now in a java thread it crash on imageProcessor.ApplyHPF()

```
private void ProcessOnce(final byte[] _data)
    {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                byte[] data = _data.clone();
                try {
                    final ImageProcessorWrapper imageProcessor = new ImageProcessorWrapper();

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        imageProcessor.ProcessFrame(data, w, h);
                        imageProcessor.ApplyHPF(); // that call crash

                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    doWork = false;

                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

somehow the second call does not find the native stored pixel array.
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa16a8000 in tid 9781 (Thread-2246)

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_troop_com_imageconverter_ImageProcessorWrapper_YUVtoRGB(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jobject handler, jbyteArray yuv420sp, jint width, jint height)
{
    jbyte* yuv = (jbyte*) env->GetByteArrayElements(yuv420sp,NULL);
    int size = env->GetArrayLength(yuv420sp);
    jint* nativeyuv = new jint[size];
    ImageProcessor* rgbContainer = (ImageProcessor*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(handler);
    memcpy(nativeyuv,yuv, size);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(yuv420sp, yuv, 0);
    rgbContainer->YuvToRgb(nativeyuv, width, height);
}


JNIEXPORT void    JNICALL Java_troop_com_imageconverter_ImageProcessorWrapper_ApplyHighPassFilter(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jobject handler)
{
    ImageProcessor* rgbContainer = (ImageProcessor*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(handler);

    rgbContainer->applyFocusPeak();
}
```

Imageprocessor:

```
class ImageProcessor {
public:
    jint _width;
    jint _height;
    int* _data;
    ImageProcessor()
    {
        _width = 0;
        _height = 0;
        _data = new int[0];
    }
}
```

my question is how can i get a vailid ref to the memory region i stored the native ImageProcessor, when calling it from a java thread?
What i read about JniEnv it returns always the context from the thread it runs. so the jnienv should be equal for both methods because its called from same thread.

Comment: Have you tried to move `byte[] data = _data.clone();` outside of your thread? I think maybe it's just because the `_data`'s memory is cleared. Just wild guess.

Comment: thats not the problem i tryed it. also the java byte[] gets copied into native mem

Comment: I found the problem. It was not real a threading problem as i thought. I init the native array in a wrong way `int* newarray[w*h];` but that way it was not init. Correct is `int* newarray = new int[w*h];`